# Tuple index out of range with working of an image in Python

Tags: python

Have a `class` Header:

```
class Header:
    MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH=8
    magicnum = "hide" #str
    size = 0
    fformat = "txt"
```

Have a fucntion, which can encode pixel in an image:

```
def encode_in_pixel(byte, pixel):
    """Encodes a byte in the two least significant bits of each channel.

    A 4-channel pixel is needed, which should be a tuple of 4 values from 0 to
    255.

    """
    r = (byte&3)
    g = (byte&12)>>2
    b = (byte&48)>>4
    a = (byte&192)>>6

    color = (r+(pixel[0]&252),\
             g+(pixel[1]&252),\
             b+(pixel[2]&252),\
             a+(pixel[3]&252)) # Here is my problem
    return color
```

After inputting correct arg in command line , while building, I have an error, which says that:

> a = pixel[3]&3
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

I was trying to input diffiret kinds of images, like: png,jpg,jpeg and etc.
Because wanted to check `A 4-channel pixel` out because I could wrong with the image. But no, I have the same error.

I would like to show , how my encoding process looks ,except `encode_in_pixel()`, I have a function ,which call `encode_in_pixel`:

```
def encode(image, data, filename, encryption=False, password=""):
    im = Image.open(image)
    px = im.load()

    #Create a header
    header = Header()
    header.size = len(data)
    header.fformat = "" if (len(filename.split(os.extsep))<2)\
                     else filename.split(os.extsep)[1]

    #Add the header to the file data
    headerdata = struct.pack("4s"+\
                             "I"+\
                             str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",\
                             header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat)
    filebytes = headerdata + data

    #Optional encryption step
    if encrypt:
        if password:
            filebytes = encrypt(filebytes, password,\
                                padding=im.width*im.height - len(filebytes))
        else:
            print "Password is empty, encryption skipped"

    #Ensure the image is large enough to hide the data
    if len(filebytes) > im.width*im.height:
        print "Image too small to encode the file. \
You can store 1 byte per pixel."
        exit()

    for i in range(len(filebytes)):
        coords = (i%im.width, i/im.width)

        byte = ord(filebytes[i])

        px[coords[0], coords[1]] = encode_in_pixel(byte, px[coords[0], coords[1]]) 
#here i'm trying to call function , where I have an error

    im.save("output.png", "PNG")
```

I can be mistake in given args, but if it is , how should I give them?

Comment: Most images do not have an alpha channel.  JPEGs *can't* have an alpha channel.

Comment: @jasonharper   Do you mean that I should take it away?

Comment: instead of RGBA use RGB

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000    thanks for this, I will try